# os.uname() function not working in Windows

Tags: python, windows, wsl-2

When I write the following code in Python in WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04):

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.uname()
```

The output is:

```py
posix.uname_result(sysname='Linux', nodename='Saqib-PC', release='4.19.104-microsoft-standard', version='#1 SMP Wed Feb 19 06:37:35 UTC 2020', machine='x86_64')
```

But when I run the same code on Windows terminal it gives me an `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'
```

**Can anyone tell me why this is happening?**

NB: Other `os` functions work fine in both.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on the existing answers.

> Can anyone tell me why is it happening?

[DeepSpace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62798394/11810933) is correct and sufficient for the main question.  `os.uname()` works under all versions of WSL, because:

- WSL1 "pretends" to be Linux via syscall translations.  That's not meant to be a negative -- It does a *really* good mob of "pretending".  In this case, it implements the Linux kernel API's needed for the [`uname` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html) to return the information for Python to populate that tuple.
- WSL2 (which wasn't *quite*, or maybe had *just* been, released at the time of this question) runs under a real Linux kernel inside a container inside a virtual machine.  Just as you would get a `uname` result in a Docker container (from the host Linux kernel), so you also get a valid result under WSL2.

However, Windows does not have a `uname` syscall, so `os.uname()` isn't implemented in Python for Windows.

###### Portable Alternative

As [IshtiukAhammed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72690882/11810933) mentions, there is also the Python `platform.uname()` call.  From the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72690882/11810933):

> Fairly portable uname interface

This method *does* work under both Linux (WSL) and Windows Python interpreters.  For example, from inside WSL:

```
$ python.exe # Launches the Windows Python interpreter, assuming it is on the path
Python 3.10.5 ... on win32

>> import platform
>> platform.uname()

uname_result(system='Windows', node='ComputerName', release='10', version='10.0.22000', machine='AMD64')

>> exit()

$ python3 # Linux/WSL
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux

>> import platform
>> import os

>> platform.uname()

uname_result(system='Linux', node='hostname', release='5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2', version='#1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022', machine='x86_64', processor='x86_64')

>> os.uname()

posix.uname_result(sysname='Linux', nodename='hostname', release='5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2', version='#1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022', machine='x86_64')
```

You'll notice some slight naming differences between the keys, but the information is pretty much the same.

While @IshtiukAhammed mentions *"extra info which is the name of [the] processor"*, the reality is that neither Linux nor Windows implement this.  Again, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.processor):

> Note that many platforms do not provide this information or simply return the same value as `for machine()`

In the case of Windows Python, `processor` simply isn't returned.  For Linux, in WSL, it is the same info as `machine`.

Of course, even without the "extra info", `platform.uname()` is a better option for portability.

Side-note:  Use caution with the Windows `release` field.  On Windows 11, this still reports `10`.  The `10.0.22000` is actually the build for the initial (21H2) Windows 11 release.

Answer (score 1):

`os.uname` is only available on a subset of `Unix` distributions/versions:.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.uname):

> Availability: recent flavors of Unix.

Without getting into technicalities, WSL is still Unix, much like a Linux VM on a Windows host is "still" Unix (and therefore, `os.uname` will be available there).

Answer (score 0):

the "os.uname()" is only available on a subset of Unix distributions/versions:-

So, it'll work on Linux based Systems ;), but won't work on Windows........

Hence, we can use the "platform.uname()" module instead. It'll provide the same infos of the "os.uname()", and also a extra info which is the name of "processor", so I think it's a better solution...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Since you quoted another answer to start out with, it really looks like you are trying to *reply* to that answer, which is done via a comment.  However, you'll need to gain some rep before you can do so.  If it's meant to be an answer, you should reference the other answer via a link and explain why your method is preferable.  The fact that it provides additional info isn't relevant to this question, which is about *portability*.  Does `platform.uname` work on Windows?  If so, then state that, and preferably show a code example.