# Error with "Docker compose up" for django project

Tags: python, django, pip, uwsgi

I have a django project, where I needed to download uwsgi for production use via the 'Docker compose up' command.
I have been following a tutorial (django by example 4, chapter 17), that also uses windows, and they did it without problems.

```
41.76   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
41.76   ERROR: Failed building wheel for uwsgi
41.76   Running setup.py clean for uwsgi
42.71 Successfully built psycopg2
42.71 Failed to build uwsgi
42.71 ERROR: Could not build wheels for uwsgi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I have tried to search for similar problems, but I can't find any. I have also asked chatGPT for any help, but it doesn't lead anywhere.

I know it has something to do with the `uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]` which probabaly should have been 'uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]', but I'm not sure.

I have been stucked with this the hole day, so I hope anywone can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [os.uname() module of python not working in windows but in wsl 2 (ubuntu 20.04)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798371/os-uname-module-of-python-not-working-in-windows-but-in-wsl-2-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: For deploying your Django project on Windows, you can consider using another WSGI server that is actually supported on Windows. Or run it on a supported platform. It's not clear how you didn't determine that this was the issue already.

Comment: @RandomDavis 
Ahhh I see. I understand the problem with uwsgi for windows now. 
The reel error, though, occured when I used "docker compose up" command, for downloading my requirement.txt with docker. As I understand it, Docker should be linux based, right?

Comment: Check the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml settings to ensure that you are using the correct base Linux image and installing dependencies properly. You should also ensure that Docker Desktop is installed and running correctly if that's relevant.